# SQL to fetch out dump data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I kind of stuck in fetching out the count of unique customers I have in sqlserver table. The way table storing data is:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|  Value   |  Label   | ClientID |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Mr       | Title    |        1 |
| Sul      | Forename |        1 |
| Last     | Surname  |        1 |
| WD17 6JJ | Postcode |        1 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Now I have to count\list unique customer on the basis of forename,surname,postcode. Can someone please help

Comment: Expected results please, and what is that design?

Comment: I just want to know the count of unique customer count or the list of that customer. Above result set was to give an idea how the information stored in database table(one table)

Comment: how do you know which surname belongs to which forename? what is the link between the customer data?

Comment: check the updated resultset

Comment: @CortezNinja Ok, that's your table which is not normalized, can you add also the expected results? Seems like you mean pivote/unpivote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two queries that will give you the desired results:

```
DECLARE @T table (Value varchar(255), Label varchar(255), ClientID int)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
('Mr', 'Title', 1)
, ('Sul', 'Forename', 1)
, ('Last', 'Surname', 1)
, ('WD17 6JJ', 'Postcode', 1)
, ('Dr', 'Title', 2) -- different Title will be ignored
, ('Sul', 'Forename', 2)
, ('Last', 'Surname', 2)
, ('WD17 6JJ', 'Postcode', 2)
, ('Mr', 'Title', 3)
, ('Sul2', 'Forename', 3) -- different Forename
, ('Last', 'Surname', 3)
, ('WD17 6JJ', 'Postcode', 3)

-- Using JOIN

SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.Value Forename
    , T2.Value Surname
    , T3.Value Postcode
FROM
    @T T1
    JOIN @T T2 ON T1.ClientID = T2.ClientID AND T2.Label = 'Surname'
    JOIN @T T3 ON T1.ClientID = T3.ClientID AND T3.Label = 'Postcode'
WHERE T1.Label = 'Forename'

-- Using PIVOT

SELECT DISTINCT
    Forename
    , Surname
    , Postcode
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            Value
            , Label
            , ClientID
        FROM @T
    ) T
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX (Value)
        FOR Label IN
            (
                Forename, Surname, Postcode
            )
    ) P
```

Comment: is there a faster way of running this? Table got 3.5 million rows

Comment: I have added an alternative query that may perform better. Is your table indexed?

Answer (score 0):

for a count of distinct Customers

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT ClientId)
FROM dbo.table
```

Or use pivot to get a distinct list

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE ( [Value] NVARCHAR(20), Label NVARCHAR(20), ClientID INT)
INSERT INTO @Table
([Value], Label, ClientID)
VALUES
(N'Mr', N'Title', 1),
(N'Sul', N'Forename', 1),
(N'Last', N'Surname', 1),
(N'WD17 6JJ', N'Postcode', 1) 


SELECT Pvt.Forename
     , Pvt.Surname
     , Pvt.Postcode
FROM @Table T
PIVOT ( MAX([Value]) FOR Label  IN ([Title], [Forename], [Surname], [Postcode])) AS Pvt
GROUP BY
     Pvt.Forename
    ,Pvt.Surname
    ,Pvt.Postcode
```

Comment: Did you see those columns(forename,surname,postcode) in the given table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       id.clientID, 
       title.title,
       Forename.Forename,
       Surname.Surname,
       Postcode.Postcode
FROM table id
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value AS title    FROM table  title WHERE label = 'title' AND title.clientID = id.clientID ) title
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value AS Forename FROM table  Forename WHERE label = 'Forename' AND Forename.clientID = id.clientID ) Forename
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value AS Surname  FROM table  Surname WHERE label = 'Surname' AND Surname.clientID = id.clientID ) Surname
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value AS Postcode FROM table  Postcode WHERE label = 'Postcode' AND Postcode.clientID = id.clientID ) Postcode
```

It's not pretty, but should work.